# Redirecting closed auction pages on eCommerce sites

Tags: seo, e-commerce, http-status-code-301

We've been optimizing a large e-Commerce auctions website for the past few months. The site may serially open and close multiple auctions for the same product - there aren't 2 auctions running in parallel for the same product. Until recently, closed auction pages were automatically removed from the site. Lately, they have decided to keep closed auction pages active while notifying users that the specific auction is closed. These closed auction pages are still being crawled and are returned in Google SERPs, sometimes above the live auction pages of the same products.

We've been contemplating some options on how to deal with closed auction pages, but are not sure which one to implement:

1. 301 redirect from closed auction pages to the relevant sub-category page of each product in question. Does having a large number of 301s bad for the site's ranking?
2. Keeping closed auction pages alive and popping up a JS widget telling the users the auction is closed and providing them with recommendations for relevant auctions on the site, preferably to a live auction of a similar product.

Does anyone have any experience specifically with auction sites and how to behave with deprecated auction pages? All of information found on the web was inconclusive and not specific to the case at hand (auction e-Commerce websites).

Thanks in advance,
Nate

Answer (score 0):

I'm not a SEO expert, so you should challenge everything I will say on that matter, but I will try to help you.

1) If you need to do that, 301 is the SEO friendly way to do it. 
301 is also known as permanent redirect and should be used if the change you want to make is permanent. The stats of the old page will be *transfered* to the new destination page.

So, on the big picture and to answer your question, a lot of 301 will not *probably* hurt your SEO.

But... you're redirecting the user to a different content and be aware that you are transferring the stats from Product page to another page that is a page with recommendations.

You can read more about it on http://seo-hacker.com/301-302-redirect-affect-seo/

Another important point is that a lot of redirects can hurt your **scalability**, because you are increasing the load on your web servers.

2) As an user perspective I would prefer to keep the closed auction page alive and just show me some information saying the auction was closed (ebay does this).

You may also show some recommendations for relevant auctions on the site, but you should be very careful with the recommendations, if they are useless you may end angering the users.